# Criterion of independence of rv's by means of support

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, independence

> Let $X,~Y$ be one dimentional ramdom variables, each one with support $S_x,~S_Y,$ respectively. Is this criterion valid?
>
> $X,~Y$ are independent if and only if the support of their joint CDF (or PDF in case of continuous rv's) is a cartesian product of the form $A\times B$.

(then two rv's whose CDF has the interior of a circle as support, can not be independent).

**Attempt.** I believe so (although I have not seen this result). For $X,~Y$ independent, the joint CDF is $F(x,y)=F_X(x)F_Y(y)$ so the support is of the form
$$\{(x,y): F(x,y)>0\}=\{(x,y):~F_X(x),~F_Y(y)>0\}=S_X\times S_Y.$$
The converse follows in the similar manner.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is not true that $F(x,y)=F_X(x)F_Y(y)$. Rather, $f_{XY}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$ where the lowercase $f$'s denote density functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is false even if you switch to talking about densities rather than CDFs. The requirement that $f_{XY}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$ is much stronger than just saying the support of $f_{XY}$ is the cartesian product of the supports of $f_X$ and $f_Y$. For example, suppose $X$ and $Y$ take values in $\{0,1\}$ with joint density

\begin{align*}
f_{XY}(0,0)=f_{XY}(1,1) &= \frac{1}{6}\\
f_{XY}(0,1)=f_{XY}(1,0) &= \frac{2}{6}.
\end{align*}

Then $f_X(0)=f_X(1)=f_Y(0)=f_Y(1)=\frac{1}{2}$, so $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

Comment: So, if $X,~Y$ are independent, then the support of $f_{X,Y}$ is the cartesian product of the supports of $X,~Y$ (and the converse is not true)?

Comment: I guess the problem has to do with the converse, while the straightforwand part is true. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, that sounds correct.